# Xbox Live User Sign In Failed on Xbox One

Tags: xbox-live

I'm testing out the new Creator's Program Unity plugin, and when running the SignInAndProfile example scene on my local machine, it signs me in correctly. However, if I try to deploy it on my Xbox One, the development console gives me the following error:

```
Warning: unknown type TaskYieldInstruction`1[Microsoft.Xbox.Services.SignInResult] detected. Using reflection to gather its type information. Consider to reference it from your scripts so it can gathered during the build process.


(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Scripting/Backend/DotNet/ScriptingTypeProvider_DotNet.cpp Line: 153)


Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in Assembly-CSharp.dll
Exception: Sign in Failed. Status: UserInteractionRequired
   at XboxLive.<SignInAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
   at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator enumerator, IntPtr returnValueAddress)
   at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.$Invoke1InvokeMoveNext(Int64 instance, Int64* args)
   at UnityEngine.Internal.$MethodUtility.InvokeMethod(Int64 instance, Int64* args, IntPtr method) 
(Filename: <Unknown> Line: 0)
```

I can't seem to find anything about what that status message means.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like your web token is invalid. You're missing some authentication.

Comment: But how come it works on the my Windows 10 device, but not the Xbox One?

Comment: Can you try hard coding some default user parameters into the code? Request a token using your credentials.

Comment: Windows 10 may have token by default. Are they both using the same xbox live account(s)?

Comment: Yes, they both use the same account. And the account is also registered as a tester on the windows dev center.

Comment: And unfortunately, I'm not able to hard code any user parameters, as it grabs the user which is logged in.

Comment: Are you using RequestTokenAsync or RequestTokenSilentAsync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting an error from RequestTokenSilentAsync, then you should try again with RequestTokenAsync which will bring up any resolution UI. 
That said I want to ask first: have you switched your console to the right sandbox? I'm guessing this is likely your issue here.

Comment: Wow.. I feel so dumb right now. Yes, I forgot to change the sandbox on the actual console, in the Dev Home app. Well, thank you! This solved the problem.